# index with where condition - Oracle

Tags: oracle12c

I would like to have an equivalent Oracle query for the below SQL Query

SQL QUERY:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ValidSub_Category ON ValidSub (Category ASC) WHERE (category IS NOT NULL)
```

purpose: This index is created to make sure that the column has more than 1 NULL records but does not have duplicate strings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably also tell us from which database your current index code is coming.

Comment: its from SQL SERVER 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX VALIDSUB_CATEGORY ON VALIDSUB (Case WHEN Category
> IS NOT NULL THEN CATEGORY END);